# Mysql Server: Unable to connect to remote host. Catalog download has failed

Tags: mysql, database

I'm getting the following message on `taskeng.exe` console:

> Unable to connect to remote host. Catalog download has failed

It seems to be related with the `manifestUpdate`. Which updates the catalog at a fixed time:

> **Automatic updates**
>
> You can configure MySQL Installer to automatically update the MySQL product catalog once per day. To enable this feature and set the update time, click the wrench icon on the Installer dashboard.
>
> The next window configures the Automatic Catalog Update. Enable or disable this feature, and also
> set the hour.

So, why am I getting that error?

I still not having very clear what's that for exactly. Does it look for possible updates of MySQL
products?

Can I disable the task to get rid of that error?

Comment: Same problem here. I just disabled it, have no idea why the error occurs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in Windows Task Scheduler. On the left, open:

Task Scheduler Library\MySQL\Installer

Right-click in the ManifestUpdate entry and select "Disable".

Original post from Andrew Clements in MySQL Forums (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,626478,626575#msg-626575)

Comment: this does solve the problem, but do you know why the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

It is a basic permission problem. Go to `C:\ProgramData` and right click on on MySQL folder, go to security tab under group users and click edit, under group and users select your computer user and select all ticks under allow, apply and close. This worked for me.

Comment: Ran the application manually after following this. Perfect, should be the answer!